# Gps CurrentLocation issues

Tags: android

My Gps settings are "off" in the beginning and I executed this code,and I can able to get CurrentLocation latitude and longitude.

But once I turned ON programatically,the settings are changed and everything is fine.

When I executed again,it is not giving me (provider,location references),I didnt understand why it is happening.

```
 public void getCurrentlocation()
{
    String providers = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    Log.e("provider",providers);
    if(!providers.contains("gps")){
      final Intent poke = new Intent();
      poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
      poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
      poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
      sendBroadcast(poke);
      Log.e("your gps is","enabled");
    }
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
       // default
       Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
       String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
       Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

       // Initialize the location fields
       if (location != null) 
       {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
              strLatitude=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
              strLongitude=String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
              Log.e("lattitude",strLatitude);
              Log.e("logntitude",strLongitude);
       }
       else 
       {
              strLatitude=String.valueOf(0);
              strLongitude=String.valueOf(0);
              Log.e("lattitude",strLatitude);
              Log.e("logntitude",strLongitude);
       }

       Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

       try {
  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(strLatitude), Double.parseDouble(strLongitude), 5);
 getAddress(Double.parseDouble(strLatitude), Double.parseDouble(strLongitude));
  if(addresses != null) {
   Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
   StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
   for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
   }
   Log.e("address",strReturnedAddress.toString());
  }
  else{
   Log.e("not found","No Address returned!");
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  Log.e("cannot get address","Canont get Address!");
 }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Location getGPSLocation(Context context) {
    try {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria cr = new Criteria();
        cr.setCostAllowed(true);
        cr.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        cr.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(cr, true);
        if(provider == null)
            provider = lm.getBestProvider(cr, false);
        return lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("NeartoMe", "Exception while fetch GPS at: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Called the above method like this. If here you are getting null means problem in fetching the gps then redirect to enable the "Use Wireless Network" in location & security settings. Then try again to fetch the GPS.

```
Location location = new Helper().getGPSLocation(context);
if(location != null) {
    latitude = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
    longitude = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
} else {
    Builder alert = new Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    alert.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.enable_use_wireless_network));
    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for lastKnownlocation, this will give you if device have any lastknown location if GPS is on then it will look for new location and lastKnownlocation may be null.

You should implement LocationListner.
Try using this:

public class GetLocationUpdate
{

```
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListner;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
TextView locLat, locLong, locInfo;
LocationProvider locationProvider;
private Context context;

/* public double mLattitude = 28.618527, mLongitude = 77.372642; */

public double mLattitude = 0.0, mLongitude = 0.0;
public static GetLocationUpdate getLocationUpdateInstance;

public static GetLocationUpdate getLocationUpdateInstance(Context context)
{
    getLocationUpdateInstance = new GetLocationUpdate(context);
    return getLocationUpdateInstance;
}

private GetLocationUpdate(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListner = new MyLocationListner();
}

public static Criteria createCoarseCriteria()
{

    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    c.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    c.setBearingRequired(false);
    c.setSpeedRequired(false);
    c.setCostAllowed(true);
    c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    return c;

}

/** this criteria needs high accuracy, high power, and cost */
public static Criteria createFineCriteria()
{

    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    c.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    c.setBearingRequired(false);
    c.setSpeedRequired(true);
    c.setCostAllowed(true);
    c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    return c;

}

public void startLocationListner()
{

    try
    {

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(

        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListner);

        mLattitude = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
        mLongitude = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLongitude();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListner);
        if (mLattitude == 0.0 || mLongitude == 0.0)
        {
            mLattitude = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
            mLongitude = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getLongitude();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.w("value : ",
            String.valueOf(mLattitude) + ":" + String.valueOf(mLongitude));

}

public void stopLocationListner()
{
    if (locationListner != null)
    {

        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListner);
        locationListner = null;
    }
}

private class MyLocationListner implements LocationListener
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {

        mLattitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        Log.w("value : ",
                String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())
                        + 


        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Constants.BRDCAST_LOCATION_UPDATED));

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        // Log.w("provider", provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        // Log.w("provider", provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        // Log.w("status", String.valueOf(status));

    }

}
```

}